# jQuery Bootstrap date picker get next week date based on choosen date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 2 textbox date from & date to using jQuery boostrap datepicker.

```
<input type="text" id="from"/>
<input type="text" id="to"/>

$('#from').datepicker(
{
    format: "dd-M-yyyy",
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Now I want when I click date picker `from`, the textbox with id `to` will be filled next week date automatic base on choose date `from`.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: "_Is it possible to do it?_" Sure, just listen to changes and when a change is detected ( [`onselect`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) ), call a function that reads the input value. Then use that to get the next week date (using [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)). Once you got it, use the new date to set the `to` input field. That is not hard, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you need from this ***"filled next week date automatic"*** but this example selected +7 days on the second datepicker from the first one selection. If you need to select whole week of second date input, you just need to change `onSelect` event inside.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#from').datepicker(
{
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    
    onSelect: function (date) {
    var date2 = $('#from').datepicker("getDate");
    var nextDayDate = new Date();
    nextDayDate.setDate(date2.getDate() + 7);
    $('#to').datepicker().datepicker('setDate', nextDayDate);
    }
    
});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <input type="text" id="from"/>
  <input type="text" id="to"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea to do that:

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: {
        /*
         * Say our UI should display a week ahead,
         * but textbox should store the actual date.
         * This is useful if we need UI to select local dates,
         * but store in UTC
         */
        toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
            var d = new Date(date);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
            return d.toISOString();
        },
        toValue: function (date, format, language) {
            var d = new Date(date);
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            return new Date(d);
        }
    }
});
```

You can also read this reference link http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#inputs

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called **[moment.js](http://momentjs.com)** which is widely spread and accepted as well in order to do the calculations on Date object

```js
$("#from").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText){
    var fromDate = new Date(dateText);
    var nextDate = moment(fromDate).add(7, 'd').format('MM/DD/YYYY'); // ---> (A)
    $("#to").val(nextDate);
    console.log("u selected", dateText);
    console.log("next date is ", nextDate);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  From Date : <input id="from" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  To Date: <input id='to' />
</body>
</html>
```

The code is pretty self-explanatory.

1. The calculation is being done in **Equation (A)** and the format is applied to just return you the date in the format asked for.
2. the calculation is happening on the date being selected.
3. I have used the callback, **onSelect()** which will be called, every time you select a date from a datePicker.